# Prevent auto increment on duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, pdo, auto-increment, duplicates

I have seen this issue around (See links at bottom) but I can't seem to figure out an answer. The problem is that I insert data on a table with an auto increment ID that is a primary key, and another field with a UNIQUE index to avoid duplicates. This works, but when that happens the ID is incremented, although no data has been stored.

**Would it be better to remove the auto increment, and handle it myself, selecting the max(ID)?**

---

At the moment I have tried several strategies to make it work as is, including `INSERT IGNORE` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

My latest try was using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO
    content(field1, field2)
SELECT(:field1, :field2) FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT field1, field2
    FROM content
    WHERE field1 = :field1
)
```

---

Related

- [In MySQL, when there is a "duplicate entry" error, how do I prevent the primary key from auto incrementing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877468/in-mysql-when-there-is-a-duplicate-entry-error-how-do-i-prevent-the-primary)
- [SQL Server - How to insert a record and make sure it is unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267804/sql-server-how-to-insert-a-record-and-make-sure-it-is-unique)

Comment: It would be better just to let it go. Such a "false increment" would not harm anyone. A duplicate of 1000s questions, by the way.

Comment: Such a "false increment" might not be a problem in some cases, but I have a large volume of data to parse, and I insert approximately 1 record for every 30 I don't. The question is more focused on the method to avoid that, the query I am using right now, or handling the auto_increment manually.

Comment: You should answer you own question (and accepted) instead of updating it with the solution, as suggested in: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456644/mysql-syntax-error-message-operand-should-contain-1-columns) I have been able to fix that error. The problem was that the `SELECT(:field1, :field2)` shouldn't have the parenthesis. So the query should be:

```
INSERT INTO
    content(field1, field2)
SELECT :field1, :field2 FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT field1, field2
    FROM content
    WHERE field1 = :field1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do an ORDER BY :)

```
UPDATE 'table' 
    SET column_id = column_id+1 
    WHERE column_id > [point where you want a un-occupied key] 
    ORDER BY column_id DESC
```

mysql executes the where and order by first then your update